# How to create a fulfillment service using Shopify api for orders?

Tags: api, shopify

I need to get all the new orders from Shopify, I receive all the orders using orders.json (GET method)

Now I should not retrieve those orders again, for that I'm trying to update the fulfillment status but getting a login error

This is the endpoint that I am using:

```
 https://valar-morghulis123.myshopify.com/admin/556026790001/fulfillments.json

{
 "fulfillment": {
 "location_id": 14388625521
     }
}
```

How to tell Shopify that those orders are already received?
Any ideas are welcome, I'm really stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a webhook on `order update` or `order fulfillment` and check the `fulfilment_status`.

> The order's status in terms of fulfilled line items. Valid values:
>
> - fulfilled: Every line item in the order has been fulfilled.
> - null: None of the line items in the order have been fulfilled.
> - partial: At least one line item in the order has been fulfilled.
> - restocked: Every line item in the order has been restocked and the order canceled.

[Source](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order#fulfillment-status-property)

If you want to update the `fulfillment_status` of the order:

```
PUT /admin/orders/#{order_id}.jso
{
    "order": {
        "id": 450789469,
        "line_items": [{
            "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
            "id": 669751112,
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: @RanjithR is your request authenticated?

Comment: yes . my fulfillment service is not automatic , its manual .. I need to update the new  orders some how , The payment status is of pending . How to do it

Comment: I need to separate the new orders with the existing one so that i can avoid duplication

Comment: You need to build a queue system with a database that you store the latest changes from the order to avoid any type of duplication. You can use the order ID to make sure that you just update an order rather than created.

Comment: The login error is most likely because there is a problem with the authentication of your request.

Comment: I have a db that stores the order now i'm trying to update that orders in shopify ,getting login errors . I checked other POST api's too ,that also getting login error